# App in Android, porting in iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, libgdx, porting

I have developed an app with Eclipse, a little stupid game.
If I wanted to port it in iOS, is there any hurting way to do it?
I mean, can I re-use xml code for GUI?
May I re-use my DB (I think so, it would be horrible if not).
If I learnt how to use libgdx or unity it would be compatible with both platforms?
Is there a good guide to understand one of them? I can't find any good guides online.

Answer (score -1):

If you write your game in Unity or PhoneGap/Cordova, it would be compatible with both devices.  I personally recommend Unity more because it's geared toward game development.

Comment: thanks for answering.
which could be a good guide to begin for one who already knows android programming via java and sdk on eclipse?